# Sort strings, treating hyphen, slash, and space as equal, using UCA collation

Tags: xslt, saxon, icu, xslt-3.0, uca

### Problem

I'm using Saxon-EE 11 and my platform's language is `en-us`.

I'm attempting to implement custom sorting behavior for an `<xsl:sort>` instruction by specifying a UCA collation. Ignoring the XML document details and just getting to the core, string-by-string comparison question, I want these strings:

```
ABSENTEES
ABSENTEE VOTING
MINNEAPOLIS TEACHERS RETIREMENT FUND ASSOCIATION (MTRFA)
MINNEAPOLIS-SAINT PAUL INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT
MINNEAPOLIS/SAINT PAUL HOUSING FINANCE BOARD
MINNEAPOLIS
MINNEAPOLIS PORT AUTHORITY
```

to be sorted into this order:

```
ABSENTEE VOTING
ABSENTEES
MINNEAPOLIS
MINNEAPOLIS PORT AUTHORITY
MINNEAPOLIS/SAINT PAUL HOUSING FINANCE BOARD
MINNEAPOLIS-SAINT PAUL INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT
MINNEAPOLIS TEACHERS RETIREMENT FUND ASSOCIATION (MTRFA)
```

Attempting to render the rules into English:

1. A string that shares a common prefix with another string, but diverges at a space should sort before that other string (`ABSENTEE VOTING` before `ABSENTEES`)
2. Hyphens and slashes should be considered the same as spaces.

### What I've tried

The UCA collation `http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?alternate=shifted` handles the `MINNEAPOLIS*` strings correctly, but it will put `ABSENTEES` before `ABSENTEE VOTING`.

The bare UCA collation `http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA` handles `ABSENTEES` and `ABSENTEE VOTING` correctly, but will place the `MINNEAPOLIS/SAINT PAUL` and `MINNEAPOLIS-SAINT PAUL` strings after anything with `MINNEAPOLIS` and a space character.

I've attempted a few other combinations of parameters, though none of them has produced anything closer to what I'm looking for. I'm close to giving up and implementing either a custom pre-processing before applying the collation or else dropping into a Java implementation.

If what I'm looking for is truly not achievable with UCA collations, that's good to know.

Comment: You might use the third argument of the `sort` function to transform your strings in the way you want

Comment: You may be right. I went with a brute force method of trying all combinations of the `strength`, `maxVariable`, and `alternate` parameters and none of them gave a collation yielding the expected results.

Comment: I've added some tags in the hope that the question will come to the attention of those who understand UCA and ICU (which is the library Saxon is using beneath the hood)

Comment: I've tried various combinations of parameters, and like you, I've failed to come up with one that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an input of:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <string>ABSENTEES</string>
    <string>ABSENTEE VOTING</string>
    <string>MINNEAPOLIS TEACHERS RETIREMENT FUND ASSOCIATION (MTRFA)</string>
    <string>MINNEAPOLIS-SAINT PAUL INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</string>
    <string>MINNEAPOLIS/SAINT PAUL HOUSING FINANCE BOARD</string>
    <string>MINNEAPOLIS</string>
    <string>MINNEAPOLIS PORT AUTHORITY</string>
</root>
```

and the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="string">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(., '-/', '  ')"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <string>ABSENTEE VOTING</string>
   <string>ABSENTEES</string>
   <string>MINNEAPOLIS</string>
   <string>MINNEAPOLIS PORT AUTHORITY</string>
   <string>MINNEAPOLIS/SAINT PAUL HOUSING FINANCE BOARD</string>
   <string>MINNEAPOLIS-SAINT PAUL INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</string>
   <string>MINNEAPOLIS TEACHERS RETIREMENT FUND ASSOCIATION (MTRFA)</string>
</output>
```

Comment: Yes, I feel it's admitting defeat, but I too have sometimes been frustrated by getting all the parameters to the UCA collation right, and have found a simple transformation on the strings to be easier.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it definitely solves the issue. My eventual solution was to actually use `fn:sort#3` and some custom tokenization to implement a word-wise sort.

I believe the core of the issue is that UCA was probably created to solve a different class of problem than what I was dealing with here..

Comment: I have found myself very frustrated with how little the I18N community seems to engage with real-world problems like sorting indexes in books. Until quite recently they were promoting collation rules for German that had been abandoned by most publishers a hundred years ago. Your desired sort order here seems so intuitive it's very hard to see why it should be difficult to achieve.